# Is it good to release these ports?

Tags: apache, port

When I am trying to start Apache server from Eclipse, I am getting message as:

> Several ports (8085, 8009) required by Tomcat v6.0 Server at localhost are already in use. The server may already be running in another process, or a system process may be using the port. To start this server you will need to stop the other process or change the port number(s).

I find the ports are opened by any process by the OS using  "`netstat -an`"

I found below data as listening.

```
TCP    0.0.0.0:8009           0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING
TCP    0.0.0.0:8080           0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING
TCP    0.0.0.0:8085           0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING
TCP    [::]:8009              [::]:0                 LISTENING
TCP    [::]:8080              [::]:0                 LISTENING
TCP    [::]:8085              [::]:0                 LISTENING
```

I don't know whether this are useful process, or can I release this ports.

Comment: How does that tell you that those ports are "opened by the OS"? Use `netstat -anp` to see process names for the sockets. Also I'm curious, how would you "release" those ports without knowing what opened them?

Comment: @MattiVirkkunen please can you help me how to proceed further, i used above command you given. Active Connections

  Proto  Local Address          Foreign Address        State              i got above output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If tomcat is already running eclipse will report this.  This could happen if eclipse crashed.

### If you only have one instance of tomcat on your machine

Try stopping it

```
bin/shutdown.sh
```

or on windows

```
bin/shutdown.bat
```

and then restarting tomcat from eclipse.

### On linux

You can verify those ports are in use by another tomcat (or the same one that is already running) with

```
netstat -anp #running as the superuser the -p option will say what the process is
```

You can then check the process table to cross reference the ports

```
ps aux | grep java
```

or

```
ps aux | grep 1234 #replacing 1234 with the PID reported by netstat
```

If it is tomcat and it won't shutdown after running `bin/shutdown.sh` then you can kill it using the `kill` commmand.

### If you do have something else that is using those ports

- edit conf/server.xml
- change the ports that tomcat will use, try 6080, 6005, etc
- start tomcat from eclipse again

Comment: iam using windows 7, i feel above commands as linux commands?

Comment: Yeah... didn't realize you were on windows.  Same principles apply: determine if it is tomcat running, shut it down or kill it.

Comment: iam very suprised as there is shutdown.bat in bin folder